# Get number of documents per month with $dateFromString

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a collection with documents which have a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD

I am trying to count the documents for each month for a given year, using an aggregation

```
col.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "DateTime": { "$gt": year + "-01-01", "$lt": year + "-12-31"}
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id":
            {"$dateFromString": {"format": "%Y-%m", "dateString": "$DateTime"}
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

However i have an error as the format of my date (YYYY-MM-DD) doesnt match with the format of the group i am creating.

How could i do to retrieve the documents grouped per month per year?

Thanks

Comment: Do you store the date values as string (what you should **never** do) or as `Date` objects?

Comment: Agree with the previous comment. For your current approach o think you have to wrap the `$dateFromString` in the `_id` of the `$group` with a [$dateTrunc operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes, you are right, thats a bad practise, but thats not code i have written, so theres not much i can do there...

Comment: @user20042973 do you reckon datetrunc would work? shouldnt be a $substr operator? I am having an error because the field is a string and not a date.

If you could paste here how you would do it i would appreciate it :)

Comment: Well right now you have `$dateFromString` and I was suggesting wrapping that. Ultimately you should update the docs to contain dates. But sure, in the meantime changing to use substr will probably suffice